# Grass averaging raster not working with: Could not read georeferenced file error

Tags: raster, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am trying to average geotiff using grass files using r.external and r.series. The geotiffs are georeferenced with wgs84. The command is below.

```
grass74 g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" r.external input="/media/geodev/Seagate Expansion Drive/chlor_a/2017/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_01_2017-18_30_00.tif" band=1 output=tmp153263774753364 --overwrite -o r.external "/media/geodev/Seagate Expansion Drive/chlor_a/2017/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_03_2017-19_55_00.tif" band=1 output=tmp153263774753365 --overwrite -o g.region n=31.4648437503 s=17.4068080185 e=-80.4330407378 w=-98.0539218184 res=0.0142218572079 r.series input="tmp153263774753364,tmp153263774753365" method=average range="-10000000000,10000000000" output="output90e1839842f5448890b14b9d0c406f01" --overwrite g.region raster=output90e1839842f5448890b14b9d0c406f01 r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output90e1839842f5448890b14b9d0c406f01 output="/home/geodev/Desktop/ava2ee4.tif"
```

However, I am getting the error below.

```
Creating new GRASS GIS location/mapset...
ERROR: ERROR 4: g.proj: No such file or directory
ERROR: Could not read georeferenced file g.proj using either OGR nor GDAL

Exiting...
```

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can create GRASS locations from the CLI using proj4 strings. You could do: `grass74 -c /path/to/file.tiff`. Adapting this to the answer from @markusN it would be: `grass74 -c /path/to/file.tif --exec sh yourscript.sh`, and `yourscript.sh` would begin with the `r.external` command, not the `g.proj` command.

Comment: Will `-c /path/to/file.tif` represent the output file?

Comment: I tried to run it in another file but I get the errors `access: No such file or directory
ERROR: LOCATION </var/www/html/web_map/simplemap/resources/py/<UNKNOWN>>
       not available
ERROR: Path '/media/myuser/Seagate Expansion Drive/chlor_a/2017/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_01_2017-18_30_00.tif/PERMANENT' doesn't exist
`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write all these commands to a text file (e.g. "yourscript.sh") and run it using the --exec parameter:

```
grass74 -c yourgeofile.tif -e /path/to/grassdata/test1/
grass74 /path/to/grassdata/test1/PERMANENT/ --exec sh yourscript.sh
```

For an example, see also here:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/grass7.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface

--> Execution of shell and Python scripts instead of single commands

Comment: I am trying to automate the above code. I can create a text file programmatically but what should I put in the text file?

Comment: Your commands from your question above! g.proj ... r.external ... etc

Comment: I did but I got an error `access: No such file or directory ERROR: LOCATION </var/www/html/web_map/simplemap/resources/py/<UNKNOWN>> not available ERROR: Path '/media/myuser/Seagate Expansion Drive/chlor_a/2017/chlor_a-modis-aqua-01_01_2017-18_30_00.tif/PERMANENT' doesn't exist` Why is PERMANENT needed when I use external file?

Comment: PERMANENT is part of the internal file structure of GRASS GIS, it contains the projection information and more. In your case, that's generated and managed automatically. From your report here I cannot see what you tried, though...

Comment: I used the above commands using the sh file.

Comment: ok you need to first generate the location. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I just checked according to your suggestion but the script only executed grass GUI without running the scripts. Also I want to run the script in a loop if I run the above code again, it will say location is set already. It seems like grass is not as a standalone tool like gdal.

Comment: It is but to get your script fixed over "chat" here is a but complex...

Comment: Thank you! That would be great. Will you be available in 8 hours from now?

Comment: I am ready to chat with you if you are online.